# Sign in with email but welcome message is the name

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make the name as like a welcome message, something like "Welcome, !" and yes there are many articles on the web that gives you coding, not when something went wrong with my code.

Anyway, my login page uses email and password:

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['login']))
 {
       $email = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['email']) ? stripslashes($_POST['email']) : false);
   $password = mysql_real_escape_string(isset($_POST['password']) ? stripslashes($_POST['password']) : false);

   if ($email&&$password)
   {
    require "connect.php";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register WHERE email LIKE '$email'");       
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if (1 == $numrows)
    {   
        $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)

        if ($email==$rows['email'] && $password==$rows['password'])
        {
            $_SESSION['email']=$rows['email'];
            $_SESSION['name']=$rows['name'];
            header("Location: profile.php");
        }
        else 
        {
            echo ('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Incorrect Password");</script>');
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        echo ('<script type="text/javascript">alert("The Email Does Not Exist In Database");</script>');
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
   }
   else 
   {
    echo ('<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please Enter An Email and/or Password");</script>');
    header("Location: index.php");
   }
}

  exit();
  ?>
<form name="flogin" action="index.php" method="post">
<table width="350px">
    <tr>
        <td ><b>Email :</b></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name="email"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Password :</b></td>
        <td><input  type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div><input type="submit" class="login" value="Login" name="login"></div> 
</form>
```

but i got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C:\xampp\htdocs\CashFlow\index.php on line 19`

and on my profile.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    require "connect.php";
    if($_SESSION['name'])
    {
$name =  $_SESSION['name'];
$query =  mysql_query("SELECT name FROM register WHERE name ='$name'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if(1 == $numrows)
{
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo "Welcome, ".$rows['name']."!"; 
    }
}
    }
    ?>
```

But I got this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\CashFlow\profile.php on line 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there i changed it but still same error. im using notepad++ so i thoroughly checked the brackets. and what about the profile.php coding?

Comment: $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)   DOES NOT HAVE A SEMI-COLON.

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
 if ($email && $password) {
    require "connect.php";
```

You never closed that bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing curly braces `}`.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { // you never closed this if statement
.....
......
}
} // Add these in your code.
exit();
?>
```